# I get message firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I get This message when i click cart To showing user-item detail to check out
i cant resolve this problem i try any method but i don't understand

this my activity.
this activity active when in Mainmenu user click Navigation bar -> cart this will active

```
public class Cartasli extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private Button checkout;
    private TextView totalHarga;

    private ArrayList<Modelcartasli>modelcartasliArrayList;
    private AdapterCartAsli adapterCartAsli;

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cartasli);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchackout);
        totalHarga = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_price);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


       // showcartasli();


       // loadcartdetail();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Cart");
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Modelcartasli> option = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Modelcartasli>()
                .setQuery(cartListRef.child("User View").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).child("BUKU").child("BukuId"),Modelcartasli.class).build();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Modelcartasli, CartViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Modelcartasli, CartViewHolder>(option) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CartViewHolder cartViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Modelcartasli modelcartasli) {
                cartViewHolder.Judulbuku.setText(modelcartasli.getPname());
                cartViewHolder.hargabuku.setText(modelcartasli.getPharga());
                cartViewHolder.Lamasewa.setText(modelcartasli.getPlamasewa());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_layout,parent,false);
                CartViewHolder holder = new CartViewHolder(view);
                return holder;

            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();
    }
```

and this my Holder.
this to hold XML Cartasliactivity, this holder to hold data from a database to activity

```
public class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public TextView Judulbuku,hargabuku,Lamasewa;
    private ItemClickListner itemClickListner;

    public CartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        Judulbuku=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_buku_judul);
        hargabuku=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_buku_harga);
        Lamasewa=itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_buku_lamasewa);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListner.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);
    }

    public  void setItemClickListner (ItemClickListner itemClickListner){
        this.itemClickListner = itemClickListner;
    }
```

i don't know what wrong,  please help me

this full error message

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.example.sewabuku2, PID: 21720
>
> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.sewabuku2.Modelcartasli

and this Modelcartasli

```
    private String pdate,pharga,pid,plamasewa,pname,ptime;

    public Modelcartasli() {
    }

    public Modelcartasli(String pdate, String pharga, String pid, String plamasewa, String pname, String ptime) {
        this.pdate = pdate;
        this.pharga = pharga;
        this.pid = pid;
        this.plamasewa = plamasewa;
        this.pname = pname;
        this.ptime = ptime;
    }

    public String getPdate() {
        return pdate;
    }

    public void setPdate(String pdate) {
        this.pdate = pdate;
    }

    public String getPharga() {
        return pharga;
    }

    public void setPharga(String pharga) {
        this.pharga = pharga;
    }

    public String getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public String getPlamasewa() {
        return plamasewa;
    }

    public void setPlamasewa(String plamasewa) {
        this.plamasewa = plamasewa;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    public String getPtime() {
        return ptime;
    }

    public void setPtime(String ptime) {
        this.ptime = ptime;
    }
}
```

this Screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SApF0.png)

and this json code

```
"Cart" : {
    "Admin View" : {
      "qM6yj9Io86TSvUyL192EudNJJTy1" : {
        "BUKU" : {
          "BukuId" : {
            "pdate" : "Dec 353, 2020",
            "pharga" : "80000",
            "pid" : "1608212863715",
            "plamasewa" : "8 Minggu",
            "pname" : "kevin1",
            "ptime" : "20:57:31 PM"
          }
        }
      },
      "wxhr6zAm0kWajjRKO9S47fpeKHX2" : {
        "BUKU" : {
          "BukuId" : {
            "pdate" : "Dec 353, 2020",
            "pharga" : "10000",
            "pid" : "1608059521100",
            "plamasewa" : "1 Minggu",
            "pname" : "cart",
            "ptime" : "20:07:55 PM"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "User View" : {
      "qM6yj9Io86TSvUyL192EudNJJTy1" : {
        "BUKU" : {
          "BukuId" : {
            "pdate" : "Dec 353, 2020",
            "pharga" : "80000",
            "pid" : "1608212863715",
            "plamasewa" : "8 Minggu",
            "pname" : "kevin1",
            "ptime" : "20:57:31 PM"
          }
        }
      },
      "wxhr6zAm0kWajjRKO9S47fpeKHX2" : {
        "BUKU" : {
          "BukuId" : {
            "pdate" : "Dec 353, 2020",
            "pharga" : "10000",
            "pid" : "1608059521100",
            "plamasewa" : "1 Minggu",
            "pname" : "cart",
            "ptime" : "20:07:55 PM"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.sewabuku2.Modelcartasli

Comment: You need to include the full stack trace.

Comment: what is that ??

Comment: Please edit your question to include the JSON at `Cart/User View/$uid/BUKU/BukuId` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).